# Why to favor static member classes over nonstatic (Joshua Bloch Item #22)?

Tags: java, design-patterns

After reading that part of the book twice I still dont get why is this so broadly stated.
Nonstatic member classes are part of the language. Agreed that not all parts of any programming language is perfect. Do the advantages of nonstatic member classes, with their access to enclosing instance's methods, so seldom outweigh the possibly increased complexity of code (the tighter coupling between the inner and the outer class. BTW: accessing fields of outer class is also possible by static member classes, as long as the outer class is static as well)?  No cons are really given in this part of the book.

What about non-static member classes for the Adapter pattern? Builder pattern?

What about non-static member classes for tiny objects (resembling e.g. C++'s struct) for keeping a few bits of data that belong together AND that belong to the outer class (so there is no reason to make them static) ?

(There seems to be a large excerpt on this item from *Effective Java 2nd Edition* by Joshua Bloch here: http://jtechies.blogspot.com/2012/07/item-22-favor-static-member-classes.html - just in case someone does not have the book handy, to know what my starting point is).

Comment: Does he not mention the space/time overhead associated with the outer-instance reference required for non-static classes?

Comment: If Bloch himself doesn't give an acceptable reason there is no reason to follow his recommendation. The 'excerpt' is either plagiarism or unrefereed third-party commentary.

Comment: @EJP: I am not going to comment on what unknown people publish. The link is what I have found googling for an answer. I have given it for the convenience of readers of this thread. My doubt relates to J.B. text contained in his original book (2dn ed.).

Comment: Saying to favor static nested classes over inner classes isn't too "broadly stated". It doesn't decry the use of inner classes, only requires that one fully understand the use cases for them. It doesn't take a "reason to make [nested types] static", _au contraire, it takes a reason not to. Another thing, containing classes can only be static if they're also nested, and doubly-nested types are bad.

Answer (score 2):

Your concerns are clearly addressed in item 22 of the book.

> Why to favor static member classes over nonstatic (Joshua Bloch Item #22)?

Answer:

> **If you declare a member class that does not require access to an enclosing
>   instance, *always* put the static modifier in its declaration**, making it a static rather than a nonstatic member class. If you omit this modifier, each instance will have an extraneous reference to its enclosing instance. Storing this reference costs time and space, and can result in the enclosing instance being retained when it would otherwise be eligible for garbage collection (Item 6). And should you ever need to allocate an instance without an enclosing instance, you’ll be unable to do so, as nonstatic member class instances are required to have an enclosing instance.

---

> What about non-static member classes for the Adapter pattern? Builder pattern?

Answer:

> One common use of a nonstatic member class is to define an *Adapter* [Gamma95, p. 139] that allows an instance of the outer class to be viewed as an instance of some unrelated class. For example, implementations of the `Map` interface typically use nonstatic member classes to implement their *collection views*, which are returned by `Map`’s `keySet`, `entrySet`, and `values` methods. Similarly, implementations of the collection interfaces, such as `Set` and `List`, typically use nonstatic member classes to implement their iterators:
>
> ```
> // Typical use of a nonstatic member class
> public class MySet<E> extends AbstractSet<E> {
>     ... // Bulk of the class omitted
>
>     public Iterator<E> iterator() {
>         return new MyIterator();
>     }
>
>     private class MyIterator implements Iterator<E> {
>         ...
>     }
> }
> ```

Comment: This answer is correct. However it's entirely composed of material the OP was already reading, so it doesn't really add anything (which is more a statement about the question rather than the answer, to be clear :)

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth I don't see the first paragraph I quoted in his link (honestly, I didn't go through all the text there, I just answered).

Comment: Thanks for comments. user1803551 highlighted the paragraphs that are the key here, indeed. Just the caption of the item #22 does not seem to match/summarize them. I have the feeling that @EJP made the point: do not follow blindly what is written, if it cannot be well grounded (or in this case: do not only rely on bold captions alone, treat the text as a whole). Unfortunately he did not extended his succinct utterance to an answer to be accepted.

Comment: @ArturOpalinski Item 22 is actually a short review on nested classes, with the bulk of it talking about static and nonstatic member classes. EJP's comment is irrelevant, because Bloch *did* given exact reasons to follow his recommendations. This answer answers the question exactly (though I did nothing more than to quote from his book).

Comment: @ArturOpalinski Is there a reason you don't want to accept this answer?